# SQL Procedure parameter to function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, cygwin

I created a procedure called details_inventory with 1 parameter "word" in MySQL Workbench. When I execute for example `CALL details_inventory("5")` then result show me the row that contains 5. Perfect! It seems that it works but the problem I have is by Cygwin (code for command line see below) make the same thing what I make on MySQL but I don't know how to use "word" parameter from procedure in my code.

```
--
-- Search inventory MySQL
--
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS details_inventory;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE details_inventory(
    word VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM search_inventory WHERE namn =word OR produktid = word OR hylla = word OR antal = word OR pris = word;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
-- test if its work
CALL details_inventory("5");
```

Cygwin code for read from command line

```
"user strict";
// Import terminal.js
const terminal = require("./src/terminal.js");

// Read from commandline
const readline = require("readline");

//Main function
(function () {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    showMenu();
    rl.setPrompt("Type menu:  \n");
    rl.prompt();

    rl.on("close", process.exit);
    rl.on("line", async (line) => {
        line = line.trim();
        let lineArray = line.split(" ");

        switch (lineArray[0]) {
            case "quite":
            case "exit":
                process.exit();
                break;
            case "menu":
            case "help":
                showMenu();
                break;
            case "log":
                await terminal.log(lineArray[1]);
                break;
            case "shelf":
                await terminal.shelf();
                break;
            case "inventory":
                if (lineArray[1]) {
                    return await terminal.inventorySearch(lineArray[1]);
                } else {
                    return await terminal.inventory();
                };
                break;
            default:
        }
        rl.prompt();
    });
})();

function showMenu() {
    console.info(
        `Hi how can I help you \n`+
        `You can type these commands: \n` +
        `exit, quite: Exists from the program. \n` +
        `help, menu: Show commands again. \n` +
        `log <number>: Show log table. \n` +
        `shelf: Type to see shelf. \n` +
        `inventory: Show inventory \n` +
        `inventory <str>: Show inventory than are u looking for. \n`

    );
}
```

Here is code for the function to show what I type in Cygwin for example "5" so result will be row that contains 5.

Where to put the word parameter? First, i was thinking to put CALL details_inventory(word); That doesn't work. When I type log 5 nothing happened in Cygwin.

```
inventorySearch: async function () {
    const db = await mysql.createConnection(config);
    console.info("Inventory you are looking for: ");

    let sql = `CALL details_inventory(word);`; 
    let res;
    console.log(sql);
    res = await db.query(sql);
    res = res[0];
    console.table(res);

    db.end();
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question, since AFAIK Cygwin does not have a JavaScript shell; you would need Node.js.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey Yes I using node.js too for that.